# Excel chart for rail car movements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I need to display the movements of a group of rail cars between two locations.

Each car has dates for "left location A", "arrived location B", "left location B", "arrived Location A" -  repeatedly over time. 
 (A is in the West and B is in the East)

How can I create a chart with one (Y axis) row for each car and show all of its movement data over time? Each time period in transition would be a bar with white space between movements.

Further, it would be nice to have the eastbound transits be green colored and westbound be yellow colored.  And maybe a vertical line for today's date

thanks for any help.

Comment: What did you try thus far?

Comment: Do you have a sample chart you're trying to copy? If so, could you please post it to a file sharing site and post a link?

Comment: I was trying using the idea of Gant charts but it's not quite the right match. I just found this and am trying it  http://peltiertech.com/easier-gantt-chart-for-repeated-tasks/    I don't have a sample chart - starting from scratch.

Comment: using the above method, I created...   hmmm, not sure to copy and paste a screenshot from windows.

Comment: using the above method, I created...   hmmm, not sure to copy and paste a screenshot from windows.     guess I can't...    I can make the chart, but still don't understand how to change the vertical axis label from the category number back to the actual rail car number.  and I'm still search on how to use another column with East or West text in it to conditionally set the barcode color  (for each displayed duration)    sorry for the clumsiness...first post

Comment: Does this sample match what you're trying to do?  If so, I'll ask the mods to undelete my now edited answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/CuPz6.png

Comment: Yes!  That captures it nicely.       Also, is imgur a good way to share pictures like that?

Comment: here's my start...  http://i.imgur.com/mw217hL.png   yours is much more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information you provided, you can create a chart similar to this. It uses a Stacked Bar Chart for the East/West trips and a series formatted as an XY/Scatter Chart for the highlighted date.

The biggest challenge is data formatting.  Assuming you started with five columns (car, to B, at B, to A, at A), you'll need to calculate the intervals which will be used for your chart.

Then, use a pivot table to create your data series for each trip segment.

[image: Rail Cars]

Here's how the original data table and the pivot table (used for the actual chart) are setup:

[image: rail cars setup]

The short version is I added a trip ID for each round trip, for each car. This becomes the basis for your data series for the chart.  Then, the first "start delay" is the actual date of for the first trip (shown in Excel serial date format).  Then all other charted values are the duration of each segment (East travel, East delay (layover duration), West travel and Start Delay (layover duration).  From there, use a pivot table with:

- Row Labels = Trip, Values
- Column Labels = Car
- Values = Sum of Start Delay, Sum of East, Sum of East Delay, Sum of West

Each of the delay series gets formatted as blank, while each of the trip values is either green or yellow.

Comment: Thank you for your time and good ideas.  I'll try that method.

Comment: Hi Dav if you're still out there.  I need a little more help getting to your solution.   I can calculate the durations of each movement but am struggling to structure the pivot table correctly.   could you give me a little more detail of how you got to the above solution?

Comment: Great!  Thanks, Dav.   I'll look at it and get going again.

Comment: Hi Dav. I'm not following how you are calculating West delay and how that is differentiated from Start Delay.

Comment: .... I think I get it now.  same as start delay. west delay is calculated and then put into start delay

Comment: my pivot table is not quite right. here's a screen shot  http://i.imgur.com/uewiHGK.png

Comment: making progress.  my pivot table doesn't look the same though. http://i.imgur.com/RKWvcvF.png        For the chart x axis,  I tried changing the pivot table sum values from displaying the serial date field to date (under the "Number Format" button of the Value Field Settings but that didn't work..   also I deleted some of the legend fields, but still would like to change the two colors to Eastbound and Westbound.  Advice?